# Setting the domain directory when installing Weblogic Server 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, webserver, weblogic, weblogic11g

During the install of WebLogic Server the installation wizard is asking where I would like to put my domain directory.  For the domain directory, is this an absolute path or a relative path? If it is a relative path, what directory does it hang off of?  I'm installing this for the first time and it leaves me to question where I should put it and what the best practice is.  Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: It does not matter. The domain directory will have to be set for each domain creation.

Comment: I found my solution.  WebLogic Server was looking for an instance that existed or was looking to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. WebLogic Server was looking for an instance that existed or was looking to create one.